# Syncing repo problem

Tags: bug-reporting

I tried to sync this repo https://github.com/kprkpr/android_device_samsung_s7560.
It stuck on 99% and no error shown. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That IS NOT an Ubuntu repo , is for an Android ROM for your phone, you can't add it to Ubuntu, but you can download the files from it via Ubuntu, like this

```
wget https://github.com/kprkpr/android_device_samsung_s7560/archive/master.zip
```

No bugs to report as it is not an Ubuntu repo and offers no packages for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu repos look like this

```
ppa:user/ppa-name
```

Example:

```
ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
```